# NumberForm giving incorrect result

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

The [definition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html) of the `NumberForm` function is the following:

"*NumberForm[expr,n]
prints with approximate real numbers in expr given to n-digit precision.*"

However when I use it, I do not get an $n$-digit precision result. A simple reproducible example is the following:

```
x = Sqrt[112345676543211];

NumberForm[N[x], 1000]
```

The result is:

```
1.059932434371224 * 10^(7)
```

Obviously this is not a $100$-digit precision of $\sqrt{112345676543211}$. What's going on?

Note that I am using Mathematica 11.1.

Comment: The problem is that `N[x]` returns by default a $MachinePrecision number. The solution : `NumberForm[N[x, 1000], 1000]`

Comment: @andre314 That solves it, post it as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: [Related, nearly duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184927/5467)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [duplicate of this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184927/5467)